# Laravel return view is not working, error page shows up instead

Tags: php, html, laravel

Im trying to return an existing view but "404 not found" shows up. Im a beginner and I don't understand Laravel than well yet. Any ideas why error 404 is showing up instead of show page? I already tried "Use View" but still nothing is working.
PostsController.php:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Post;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Services\SlugService;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
     /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('blog.index')
            ->with('posts', Post::orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->get());
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('blog.create');
    }
    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  string  $slug
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

//NOT WORKING THIS
    public function show($slug)
    {
        return view('blog.show')->with('post', Post::where('slug', $slug)->first());
    }
...
```

show.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="w-full m-auto text-center">
    <div class="py-15 border-b border-gray-200 w-full">
        <h1 class="text-4xl uppercase">
            {{ $post->title }}
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="px-5">
    <span class="text-gray-500">
    By <span class="font-bold italic text-gray-800">{{$post->user->name}}</span>
    , Uploaded on {{date('jS M Y', strtotime($post->updated_at))}}
    </span>

    <p class="text-xl text-gray-700 pt-8 pb-10 leading-8 font-light">
        {{ $post->description }}
    </p>
</div>

@endsection
```

These are my routes.
web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\PagesController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PostsController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', [PagesController::class, 'index']);

Route::resource('/mods', PostsController::class);

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

Comment: Post your route

Comment: @sta i posted them

Comment: make sure show.blade.php is in the right folder (../resources/views/blog/show.blade.php)

Comment: it is there, yes

Comment: You need to define the route

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information but you can follow the below debugging step yourself.

1. Figure out if it is your route issue or the view issue. **More likely it is your routing not the view.** Because if Laravel cannot find your view file, you will see an `InvalidArgumentException` error instead. Add a debug code before the return. For example, you can add a `dd()` before your return statement. If your request reach the correct route, you will see a debugging `dd` instead of 404
2. If you do not see the `dd()`. The issue is not with your view but with your route. What you can do is **try to clear your route cache**. `php artisan route:clear` This will clear the routing file cache.
3. When you write your route file like this

```php
Route::resource('/mods', PostsController::class)
```

You are using the default [RESTful resource controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) pattern come with Laravel. So, behind the scene, your show route is actually something like

```php
Route::get('/mods/{mods}', 'PostsController@show');
```

Make sure your request goes to the correct route. To do so, you can run `php artisan route:list` to verify the correct routing, and compare with the request initializer, whether it was a link or an ajax.